# Why an abstract class is "considered incomplete"?

Tags: java, abstract-class

We known that an abstract class is an incomplete class (all its methods are unimplemented - # abstract method), but abstract class is also known that "a class is **CONSIDERED INCOMPLETE**". So, what is the correct meaning (definition) of **CONSIDERED INCOMPLETE**, is that a class can have both implemented and unimplemented method? or another context?

Please let me know, thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see what you're struggling with here, besides just the definition of those English words. "*We know [it] is an incomplete class*" is the same as saying "We can consider it incomplete"

Comment: @Michael: The Java Specification mentioned that "An abstract class is a class that is incomplete, or to be considered incomplete", I think that "complete" and "to be considered incomplete" are two different concepts. It means that "complete" is all methods are unimplemented whereas "to be considered incomplete" is AT LEAST ONE method is unimplemented. I'm not sure about that, what's your idea?

Comment: It is just a tautology and you are reading too much into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification says "An abstract class is a class that is incomplete, or to be *considered* incomplete" because you can have an abstract class that is fully implemented (see [`java.awt.event.MouseAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) as an example). *Technically*, it is complete, but it is not meant to be used this way.

Nowadays, one might implement those abstract adapter classes by interfaces with default methods (if for that particular case an interface would be appropriate for that purpose at all …).

---

The idea behind the adapter classes was to provide a base implementation of particular interface that allows only those methods that are of interest for the current use case.

The interfaces `java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener` and `java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener` that are implemented by `java.awt.event.MouseAdapter` are not very well suited to illustrate the benefit of this approach, because they do have only two or one method. In addition, that `MouseAdapter` class implements also `java.awt.event.MouseListener` but does not implement any method from that interface …

So lets have a closer look to the class [`java.awt.event.KeyAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) that implements the interface [`java.awt.event.KeyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html). According to the description for [`java.awt.event.KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html), an implementation of `KeyListener` will receive three events for each character you type (for the exact details, refer to the description of `KeyEvent`):

1. KEY_PRESSED – handled by [`keyPressed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent))
2. KEY_TYPED – handled by [`keyTyped()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent)), but only if a valid Unicode character could be generated
3. KEY_RELEASED – handled by [`keyReleased()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent))

If your program wants to respond to text input only, it is only interested on the KEY_TYPED events and the implementations of `KeyListener.keyPressed()` and `KeyListener.keyReleased()` could remain empty (although they have to be implemented nevertheless!).

In case you program is an implementation of a game of some kind, you might be more interested in the pressed keys; in that case, `KeyListener.typed()` may remain empty.

Next, these listener interfaces are often used as anonymous classes, like this:

```
…
KeyListener listener = new KeyAdapter()
{
    @Overwrite
    void keyTyped( KeyEvent event )
    {
        // Do something with the event …
    }
}
…
```

Without using the adapter class, the same code would look like this:

```
…
KeyListener listener = new KeyListener()
{
    @Overwrite
    void keyReleased( KeyEvent event ) { /* Does nothing */ }

    @Overwrite
    void keyPressed( KeyEvent event ) { /* Does nothing */ }

    @Overwrite
    void keyTyped( KeyEvent event )
    {
        // Do something with the event …
    }
}
…
```

The additional lines do not contribute to readability, not really.

As said, if the methods in the interface would provide an empty default implementation, the second version (`new` *`Interface()`*`{…}`) would look like the first one.

---

These adapter classes are only one possible use case for an abstract class that does not contain any abstract method. But I confess that most of them would work better with default methods in interfaces – since these default methods made their way into Java, of course! The adapter classes are there since Java 1.1, I think … like those phrase from the language specification!

Comment: If all methods are empty, why don’t we declare abstract methods instead of empty methods?@tquadrat

Comment: @locobe: Because you have to implement an abstract method, while you can leave an empty class as it is. The purpose of the adapter classes is to have a default implementation (doing nothing or nothing useful) for the respective interface that allows you to implement only those methods you need.

Comment: thank you for your response. But, if "java.awt.event.MouseAdapter" has only empty method, why we don't use ordinary class? @tquadrat

Comment: @locobe – I have updated my original answer to respond to your comments. I hope that clarifies it. Feel free to add further comments if not!

Comment: thank you, I understand why we use adapter class. But, I don't understand why we use public abstract class KeyAdapter whereas public class KeyAdapter with empty method is fine? because you can override all methods laterly

Comment: @locobe – you are right, for some of those adapter classes, making them abstract is not necessary at all: you can also overwrite the empty methods when the class is concrete. But take that being abstract just as a marker, a reminder that this class is not meant to be used as is.

Comment: Technically, there are no differences between using an empty concrete method in concrete class or abstract class. But, according to business purpose, sometimes, we don't want to instantiate a meaningless object from abstract class, so using abstract class is better even if you can always use concrete class -@tquadrat

Comment: Additionnally, except Adapter, I think it is seldom to use empty method in abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, an abstract class CAN have just method signature/contract stating what the method name is, what arguments it take (if any) and what return type it has (or void) if it doesn't return anything - BUT without actually implementing it. And lets imagine, you create an object of this class (which by the way you can not) but if you would just for the sake of discussion, and then CALL one of those abstract methods where implementation was not provided, what do you think should happen? Basically, you are trying to call something that does not have implementation at all and that will be invalid. And hence, since there is a possibility of one or more methods not implmented in your the abstract class, we considereded an abstract class as more of a contract than considering it as fully implemented/complete class.

Answer (score 0):

An *abstract class* is used to abstract simple logic from a *real instance*.

Logic is always relative incompelete to real event or instance. For example, Cat and Tiger can all roar, but their voices are different. So, we can abstract the `roar()` method, which is logic. And then implement the method by using different voice like `miao~~miao~~` and `aowu~~aowu~~` which are real instance.

You can see it, logic is simple and refined, but it is incomplete, while real instance is completed but redundant.

**Question**: Is that a class can have both implemented and unimplemented method? or another context?

**Answer**:
You don't have to implement all methods of an abstract class but you must implement all abstract methods of it.

In fact, extending an abstract class has no difference then extending a normal class. It's not like implementing interfaces. Since you're extending you are creating a subclass, thus you can add as many methods and attributes as you need.